# Why can I instantiate a class without a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, constructor

How is it possible that class in C# may has no constructors defined?
For instance I have a class

```
internal class TextStyle
{
    internal string text = "";
    internal Font font = new Font("Arial", 8);
    internal Color color = Color.Black;
}
```

And in the code this class is instantiated as

```
TextStyle textParameters = new TextStyle();
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you don't declare any constructors for a non-static class, the compiler provides a public (or protected for abstract classes) parameterless constructor for you. Your class effectively has a constructor of:

```
public TextStyle()
{
}
```

This is described in section 10.11.4 of the C# 4 spec:

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided. That default constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct base class. If the direct base class does not have an accessible parameterless instance constructor, a compile-time error occurs. If the class is abstract, then the declared accessibility for the default constructor is `protected`. Otherwise, the declared accessibility for the default constructor is `public`.

The only classes in C# which don't have *any* instance constructors are static classes, and they *can't* have constructors.

Comment: I'm writing a unit test that requires a [`BlobDownloadInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobdownloadinfo?view=azure-dotnet) instance. Despite this class seemingly having no constructor, i.e. you'd expect `new BlobDownloadInfo()` to work, the compiler is complaining `'BlobDownloadInfo' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`. So I'm guessing something (somewhere) has changed since this answer was written.....

Comment: Seems this class can somehow (voodoo?) only be [generated using a factory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/e002645ffbe4669e0a4315fb93348465fdff5d96/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/tests/UnitTests.cs)

Comment: @Liam: I can't easily find the source to that class (via a two minute search...) but I'd expect it to have a constructor - just not a publicly accessible one. If it didn't have any constructors declared in the source code, I'd expect to see the parameterless one generated by the constructor to be documented (presumably without any text, just its presence being noted). Nothing has changed in the *language* here.

Comment: @Liam: Now found the source code, and as expected, there's an internal constructor: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/548336e6537d87ee9c1a179b7677620dddf13225/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/Models/BlobInfo.cs#L79